# quadratic constraint feasibility in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

Suppose that A is an n x n matrix, and I have observed some entries of A, say, A_S for some subset S in {1,...,n} x {1,...,n}. I want to know if it's possible that A has rank 1.

So this can be reformulated as the following question: does there exist vectors x and y such that xy^T restricted on S equal to the observed values A_S?

By concatenating x and y, say, let z = [x;y], we can write this constraint as a quadratic form in z. How to test if the constraint is feasible in Matlab?

Comment: I just thought I had come up with a nice easy solution and deleted the comment that was previously here, but then I realized it's late and I'm being an idiot. Anyway: the problem is biconvex, so local minima are going to be an issue. It may (or may not) be easier to actually find such an x and y, using (say) the total squared error on the observed points as your objective. This is a standard matrix factorization problem, and it's a nice smooth objective, though local minima are a problem. So if you find an x/y that work, you know it could be rank 1; if you don't, it may still be rank 1.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll find [`fmincon`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html) helpful in your case.
Leave the objective function zero, and code the non-linear equality constraint to be your quadratic constraint.

#### EDIT: (example of defining the quadratic constraint function)

Write an m-function:

```
function err = myQuadEqCon( z, n, S, A_s )
% given z ( a concatanation of x and y n-vectors ) and a set of entries S
% checks (x*y')(S) == A_s
x = z( 1:n );
y = z( (n+1):end );
xy = x*y.';
err = sum( abs( xy(S) - A_s ) );
```

Now, in your "main" function/script, make sure you have `n` (the dimensionality of the problem), `S` and `A_s` defined properly, then

```
>> z = fmincon( @(z) 0, ... % objective function plays no role
                z0, ... % your initial guess for x and y
                [], [], [], [], [], [], ... % linear constraints are empty
                @( z ) deal( 0, ... % first output nonlinear inequalities
                             myQuadEqCon( z, n, S, A_s ) ) );
```

Comment: The non-linear constraint function would depend on S, which would be a dynamic set. How shall I handle this?

Comment: @user58955 Closures! You can either define an anonymous function, or write a function that returns a reference to a sub-function.

Comment: Could you refer to me some example online? I am new to function pointers, etc, in matlab...

Comment: @user58955 please see my edit. google "`deal` and annonymuse function in matlab" to see hoe to return more than one output from annonymuse function. See "Passing Extra Parameters" link in the help page of `fmincon` for more information.